# TypeError: must be str, not bytes Error

Tags: python

In a python code of mine, I am getting this error while execution of this line.

```
fo.write(text.replace("'","").encode("utf8"));
```

Error :

```
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

It was working fine with python 2.7 but with 3, it is giving error.

Comment: What is the content of `text`

Comment: @kasparg, It is not working too. Hitesh Dharamdasani, It is simple text data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 3, file objects opened in text mode require you to write *Unicode text*.

You encoded your text to UTF-8 bytes, but it is the responsibility of the file object to do the encoding. Don't encode the text.

You can get the same behaviour in Python 2, by using the [`io.open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) rather than the built-in `open()` function. The `io` module in Python 2 is a backport of the new I/O infrastructure used in Python 3.

If you need to write polyglot code (Python code that works both on Python 2 and Python 3), simply import from `io`:

```
import io

with io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8') as fo:
    fo.write(text.replace("'",""))
```

The Python 3 built-in `open()` function is the exact same function as `io.open()`.

Comment: If I remove encoding to utf, then I get this error `File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 26-32: chara
cter maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @bogojane: you do need to specify the correct codec when opening the file.

Comment: You could use `fo = codecs.open(filename, 'w', encoding='UTF-8')`. That should run with Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: @Matthias: The `codecs` I/O implementation has several long-standing issues and should really be avoided. `io` works on Python 2 and Python 3 and is a lot better engineered.

Comment: You're right. I just looked up the differences between `io.open` and `codecs.open` (e.g. handling of text files) and won't recommend `codecs.open` anymore.

Comment: OK. Now I am able to write text to file. Thanks for help.